# Ubuntu 14.10 Refuses to Login to New User with Existing /home Directory

Tags: login, 14.10

So I needed to create a new account on my laptop running Ubuntu 14.10 (an install only one day old). So I went into Settings, chose User Accounts, and then added a user and a password. Then I logged out to switch users.

When I typed in the password and hit enter on the new account, the screen goes black for a short while (as if the account was loading). Then it takes me back to the login screen and plays the drum sound again. Any thoughts?

EDIT 1: `namei -m ~kenny` outputs  the following

```
f: /home/kenny
drwxr-xr-x /
drwxr-xr-x home
drwxr-xr-x kenny
```

I also forgot to mention, my previous install of 14.04 had a separate partition for the /home directory. I kept that partition and have my current install of 14.10 mapped to use that partition. So of course, my new user's old home folder is full of files and exists. Should I delete some config files?

Comment: It's possible the home directory was not properly created. Could you open a terminal, and run `namei -m ~user2` (where `user2` is the second username, so the whole command is like `namei -m ~muru`), and edit your question add the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting almost all of the hidden files and folders from my existing home directory (except folders .ssh and .gnupg), I was able to successfully login.